# How to pass compiler flags from Autoconf to Automake?

Tags: autotools, autoconf, automake, compiler-options

I'm having a heck of a time getting compiler options from Autoconf into Automake. Some of my source files have [Automake per-object flags](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Per_002dObject-Flags.html):

```
## Makefile.am
librijndael_simd_la_SOURCES = rijndael-simd.cpp
librijndael_simd_la_CXXFLAGS = $(AES_FLAG)
```

`AES_FLAG` needs architectural flags for IA-32, Aarch32/64 and Power8. Other platforms don't get a flag. Formerly, the flags were hard-coded in `Makefile.am`.

I am trying to hard-code the options in Autoconf as I am building out initial Autotools support:

```
# configure.ac
AC_SUBST([GCM_FLAG], [-mssse3 -mpclmul])
AC_SUBST([AES_FLAG], [-msse4.1 -maes])
AC_SUBST([SHA_FLAG], [-msse4.2 -msha])
...
AC_OUTPUT(Makefile)
```

But it results in:

```
$ ./configure
...

checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
./configure: line 16195: -mpclmul: command not found
./configure: line 16199: -maes: command not found
./configure: line 16201: -msha: command not found
```

The Autoconf manual, [3.1.2 The Autoconf Language](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Autoconf-Language.html#Autoconf-Language), says to use double brackets (`[[` and `]]`):

```
AC_SUBST([[GCM_FLAG]], [[-mssse3 -mpclmul]])
AC_SUBST([[AES_FLAG]], [[-msse4.1 -maes]])
AC_SUBST([[SHA_FLAG]], [[-msse4.2 -msha]])
```

It results in (I guess this is why most people don't follow the manual):

```
$ autoreconf --force --install
...

error: AC_SUBST: `[AES_FLAG]' is not a valid shell variable name
configure.ac:50: the top level
autom4te: /usr/bin/m4 failed with exit status: 1
aclocal: error: echo failed with exit status: 1
autoreconf: aclocal failed with exit status: 1
```

I believe this is the documentation, but it does not provide examples or troubleshooting steps: [7.2 Setting Output Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.64/html_node/Setting-Output-Variables.html).

Naively, I thought there would be 1000's of blogs showing how to perform this simple task, but it does not appear so: [autoconf pass compiler option to automake](https://www.google.com/search?q=autoconf+pass+compiler+option+to+automake).

How does one pass compiler flags from Autoconf to Automake?

Comment: Can you add your `Makefile.in` or `Makefile` segments that deals with _GCM_FLAG_ and others?

Comment: Thanks @Vicente. I never got that far (i.e., far enough to where my `Makefile.am` was turned into a `Makefile`).

Comment: Only in rare situations do you need or want double brackets.

Comment: If, as I suspect, it turns out that the solution you discovered does not do what you think, then I urge you to present a [mcve].  I don't see anything inherently wrong with the single-bracket approach you started with.

Comment: Just for the sake of know what happened can you show the line nearby 16195 in the configure file.

Answer (score 2):

It looks that your configuration is correct. There might be a *newline* or any other character in your `Makefile.am` or `configure.ac` file which is screwing up your building system.

I advise to see the generate `Makefile`. You can do a `grep -nC5 AES_FLAG Makefile` to see how it looks like. That might give us some hints.

Comment: Thanks @Vicente. The issue was tracked down to a lack of quotes. That is, I needed to use `AC_SUBST([GCM_FLAG], ["-mssse3 -mpclmul"])`. Neither single or double brackets was sufficient.

Comment: @jww I am happy you solved this enigma. I was quite puzzled by your question!

Comment: @jww, I, too, am glad you solved your problem, if indeed you did.  But the solution you describe does not make sense.  Your `autoreconf` error may have gone away, but watch out: I suspect you'll end up specifying different flags than you think you're doing.